# Issue Using Java AWT Robot class

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I am using the robot class and trying to stroke the keys `ctrl+alt+del`
Below is the code

```
public class RobotClassDemo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {
             Robot robot = new Robot();

             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
             System.out.println("ctrl pressed");
             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
             System.out.println("alt pressed");
             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
             System.out.println("delete pressed");

         } catch (AWTException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } 
     }
 }
```

But it is not giving me any option like I am asuming here that it will move to screen which will contain lock , shut down , change password etc.(as in window 7 happens when we press ctrl+alt+del).I am running this program on windows 7.I sthere any limitations or access previliges? Or what is the problem?
 **Edit:** Even My this code is working great

```
public void alt_tab() {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.delay(100);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
}
```

But dont know what is the problem with the first one

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be completely surprised if this were forbidden by the OS or environment; however, have you tried adding `robot.keyRelease` events?  At the moment it's as though you're holding the keys down forever.  This may be insufficient to fire the appropriate key up/down/press events that the OS uses to recognise this key combination.

Comment: but I am able to press other keys.I made a program which opens a notepad and then write my name in it using this Robot class.If those keys are pressing/executing fine then what is the problem with these keys

Comment: It looks as though the OS you are using has some special treatment of this key combination.  This link suggests ways that one might disable this behaviour: http://kb.realvnc.com/questions/91/I+can%27t+send+a+Ctrl-Alt-Delete+combination+to+my+Windows+7+computer

Comment: But I am able to send this combination from keyborad.Even though my  code present in edit section of question with key combinations is working great

Comment: Yes, the article I link says just that.  You need to turn that particular restriction off before you are able to automate the sending of this key sequence in any programmatic manner.